# python multiprocessing pool.map hangs when calling tensorflow/keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-multiprocessing

I use pool.map from multiprocessing to parallelize my python code. When I call my tensorflow/keras model with pool.map, the code hangs if my neural network is larger than a certain size. I still have plenty of RAM available, and calling the model outside of pool works fine.

I use python 3.7, tensorflow 2.3 on linux.

A mwe is provided below, it is also [on colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hn8GhMuZzSKhwj9qCOcWS3ewzOT9MG3b?usp=sharing):

```
def my_function(i):
    a = MODEL(np.array(i).reshape(1,1))
    print('foo', i)
    return a

THREADS = os.cpu_count()
N = 4
NEURONS = 150000  # works for 100000, hangs for 150000
MODEL = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(NEURONS, input_shape=(1,))])

my_function(10) # works fine

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(THREADS)
_ = pool.map(my_function, range(N)) # hangs
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Any idea what the issue is? How can I call a large model in parallel?

Edit: the size of a is not the issue, and the code hangs only if tf.keras is called once outside of pool, see mwe below and [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YITyD1gxncmGR8UFNXaslwjlKzaScHwR?usp=sharing). The critical number of neurons is lower than in the original example. Any idea?

```
def my_function(i):
    print('start', i)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(NEURONS, input_shape=(1,))])
    print('finish', i)
    return None

THREADS = os.cpu_count()
N = 4
NEURONS = 20000 # works with 10000, not with 20000

# works
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(THREADS)
_ = pool.map(my_function, range(N))
pool.close()
pool.join()

# works
my_function(10)

# doesn't work if many neurons
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(THREADS)
_ = pool.map(my_function, range(N))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: I had similar issues when I was using multiprocessing.Queue: The Queue would transfer small data, but hung for large data. (I should mention that I was careful to not have a deadlock.) So I ended up using multiprocessing.Manager to make a Queue and use that managed Queue to transfer my data and that worked fine. So in your case, I would suggest you to use a managed Queue or managed Dict to store the results from the pool rather than returning the result with `return a`.

Comment: @Ali_MM it's the call the model which is the issue though, not the size of a, I've edited my question

Comment: It looks like running the `my_function(10)` disrupts the model creation in the child processes. Comment `my_function(10)` and you will see that the second pool also works. I don't know the reason!

Comment: Yes but I need my_function(10). It seems indeed that I cannot create child processes that use tf.keras if the parent process has used tf.keras (although it hangs only for large models, small ones work fine). The best workaround I've found is to execute my_function(10) as a child process too, such that tf.keras in never called by the parent, but that's not really satisfying.