# simple snippet tensorflow+keras model prediction with multiprocessing always freezing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing, freeze

I have the following simple snippet that reproducibly freezes in the prediction step during the multiprocessing while running fine through the initial prediction (the line "predict(-1)").  It also works fine if I remove the "predict(-1)" line but I need to be able to do both the multiprocessing prediction and the initial prediction(s) in my real code.  Can anyone explain what is going on and how to fix this?  I am using python 3.9 and CUDA 11.5.  It runs on CPU and there is plenty of RAM, so not HW related.

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.set_visible_devices([],'GPU')

def predict(i):
  print(i)
  import unet
  unet = unet.unetmodel((48,48,1))
  unet.load_weights('weights.ckpt').expect_partial()
  ones=[np.full((48,48),1),]                 # generating some input
  inp_windows = np.expand_dims(ones,axis=-1) # expanding to the required dim.
  pred_windows = unet.predict(inp_windows)   # predict
  print(pred_windows[0,0,0])

predict(-1)                                  # works

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
proc=[]
for i in range(2):
  proc.append( multiprocessing.Process(target=predict, args=(i,)) )
  proc[i].start()
for p in proc:
  p.join()
```

The unet.py contains just a typical unet implementation.

I tried moving the unet defition in the code, the import statements between the global and the function, adding a multiprocessing lock etc - nothing helped.

It seems very similar to this thread:
[python multiprocessing pool.map hangs when calling tensorflow/keras model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67491252/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-hangs-when-calling-tensorflow-keras-model)

however, no solution was proposed there either.